# Average days from dates Mysql, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, average

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate DateDiff in SQL in Days:Hours:Mins:Seconds format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800185/calculate-datediff-in-sql-in-dayshoursminsseconds-format)

I have this MySql query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(hit_date), MIN(hit_date)) / (COUNT(hit_date) - 1) AS hitavg FROM my_table
```

This returns a value (average days between recorded rows from hit_date column, this column is in TIMESTAMP format, so YY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS)

Assuming that this value is 385.500 (returned from the query), how can I format in PHP this number as ***385 Days, "n" Hours*** (where "n" is the decimal value, in this case 500)?

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: Do you simply want days and hours, or did you want days, hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: @crush Simply days and hours. Sorry, I'm learning PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you only want Days and Hours, then:

```
$value = 385.500;

$days = (int) $value;
$hours = 24 * ($value - $days);

echo "$days Days, $hours Hours";
```

Comment: I replaced `floor()` with `(int)` because casting to int is 2x faster than calling `floor()` and achieves the same result.